# Apple Shortcuts app - saving text files with a different extension

Tags: markdown

When trying to save a text file with a different extension Shortcuts always appends the `.txt` extension to the file name.
For example when trying to extract text from notes or clipboard, convert them to Markdown and save the output to a file `some-title.md`, the saved file will be called `some-title.md.txt`.

Shortcut example:
[image]

How can I enforce the desired extension?

Answer (score 1):

I feel Apple's design restriction to not set your desired file extension to save it is a poor choice.

In order to workaround this, you need to first save a file as .txt and then rename it. Like this (see the image below):

[image: example of the walkaround]

Here is an [iCloud sharing link to the shortcut needed and described below](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/748e1b133e0c42b0982c62feb0f52d1d):

In this example, I am converting an article fetched using Safari Reader into a markdown, and saving it into my [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md) vault. I first save it as a text file with .txt file extension (file name is ok with anything because we’ll rename it anyway but in this case, I set it to the article’s title), and then rename it into .md .